# Is it possible to integrate Linux servers SSH with ADFS for authentication?

Tags: ssh, users, ldap

I'm having trouble managing users on 30 servers I have on AWS. From my research, I saw that it's possible to do this using FreeIPA and SSSD, but the communication is direct between the Linux servers and Active Directory. I don't want to do this type of configuration for security reasons.

I already have an ADFS Proxy in the DMZ of my network. Is it possible to integrate with ADFS instead of AD so that users can authenticate to the Linux servers? And would it be easier to have a server in the "middle" between the Linux servers and the ADFS server?

Comment: The authentication portion of SSSD<->FreeIPA is LDAP, which AD also supports.  Are LDAP auth and group permissions sufficient for the needs of your AWS Linux servers, or do you need Kerberos too?